# How do I solve regular expression expansion when I have "+" sign?

Tags: regular-expressions

For example, I am given this and my output is:

11+11* = 11, 1, 11, 111, 1111, ......

Since + means or sign, my logic is:

11 appears once or more

Then I work on solving 11*

Is it perfect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the place  of '+', we have different argument, for example:
$$1+0$$
'+' sign equivalent to union ($\cup$), so
$$1\cup 0.$$
But at another example, $11^+$ means, the second 1 can repeated once or more than once.

Hence, if $+$ appears in exponent of some alphabet, we use that to show  the number of repetition is at least one. other wise, if $+$ appears  between some alphabet, we conclude that it work as union symbol.